# Как удалить текст из всех QLineEdit на странице, по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qt-designer

Вот страница с `QLineEdit` и кнопкой. Хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки `"ERACE EVERYTHING"` весь текст, который содержится в любом из `QLineEdit` на странице удалился. Пробовал метод `clear` у `QLineEdit`, но не получилось. Может я что-то не так делаю?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew1wD.png

```python
    import sys
    import platform
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QPropertyAnimation, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt, QEvent)
    from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
    
    # import FUNCTIONS
    from ui_functions import *
    
    ## ==> SPLASH SCREEN
    from ui_splash_screen import Ui_SplashScreen
    
    ## ==> MAIN WINDOW
    from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
    
    ## ==> GLOBALS
    counter = 0
    
    # YOUR APPLICATION
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            # super().__init__()
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.resize(1920, 1080)
            self.setWindowTitle('Math Tool')
            self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('D:\MathTool_splash\math-tool-icon.ico'))
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
            # clear buttons
            self.lineEdit_10 = QLineEdit('Hello World!')
            self.clear_btn_1 = QPushButton('Click!')
            self.ui.clear_btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.lineEdit_10.clear)
    
    
            # self.lineEdit = QLineEdit('Hello World!')
            # self.clear_btn_1 = QPushButton('Click!')
            # self.clear_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
            #
            # layout = QVBoxLayout()
            # layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
            # layout.addWidget(self.clear_btn_1)
            #
            # self.setLayout(layout)
    
    
    
            # TOGGLE MENU
            self.ui.Btn_Toggle.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True))
    
            # PAGES
            #############
    
            # PAGE 1
            self.ui.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_1))
            # PAGE 2
            self.ui.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_2))
            # PAGE 3
            self.ui.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_3))
    
    
            # MAIN WINDOW LABEL
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1500, lambda: self.ui.label.setText("<strong>SOON</strong>"))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1500, lambda: self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363942; color: #82de3b"))
    
    
    
    
    
    # SPLASH SCREEN
    
    class SplashScreen(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_SplashScreen()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
            ## UI ==> INTERFACE CODES
            ########################################################################
    
            ## REMOVE TITLE BAR
            self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    
    
    
    
            ## DROP SHADOW EFFECT
            self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
            self.shadow.setBlurRadius(20)
            self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
            self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
            self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 60))
            self.ui.dropShadowFrame.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
    
            ## QTIMER ==> START
            self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)
            # TIMER IN MILLISECONDS
            self.timer.start(35)
    
            # CHANGE DESCRIPTION
    
            # Initial Text
            self.ui.label_description.setText("<strong>WELCOME</strong> TO MY APPLICATION")
    
            # Change Texts
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1500, lambda: self.ui.label_description.setText("<strong>LOADING</strong> DATABASE"))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.ui.label_description.setText("<strong>LOADING</strong> USER INTERFACE"))
    
    
            ## SHOW ==> MAIN WINDOW
            ########################################################################
            self.show()
            ## ==> END ##
    
        ## ==> APP FUNCTIONS
        ########################################################################
        def progress(self):
    
            global counter
    
            # SET VALUE TO PROGRESS BAR
            self.ui.progressBar.setValue(counter)
    
            # CLOSE SPLASH SCREE AND OPEN APP
            if counter > 100:
                # STOP TIMER
                self.timer.stop()
    
                # SHOW MAIN WINDOW
                self.main = MainWindow()
                self.main.show()
    
                # CLOSE SPLASH SCREEN
                self.close()
    
            # INCREASE COUNTER
            counter += 1
    
    class Window2(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle('kwakk')
    
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = SplashScreen()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: я добавил скриншот самой формы. надеюсь это поможет. помогите пожалуйста мне, это очень важно, а я нигде не могу найти решение(((

Comment: если вам действительно нужна помощь, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: извините, что туплю. до этого никогда не пользовался стаком. я добавил основной код программы

Comment: Sorry, МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ - это значит, что пример должен содержать 
только информацию, которая относится к проблеме.
В вашем случае это виджеты `QLineEdit` и кнопка "ERACE EVERYTHING".
Важно видеть как вы располагаете эти `QLineEdit`'ы, 
какие менеджеры компоновки вы используете для построения окна.

Comment: ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ - это значит, что ваш код просто копируется,
запускается и приложение работает.

При этом учтите, что если дизайн создан в `Qt Designer`  
и сконвертирован `pyuic5`, вам надо предоставить (опубликовать) 
модуль например `ui_main.py`.

То что вы опубликовали, к сожалению, не является ни минимальным, ни воспроизводимым примером